# Split loop result to a range in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code

```
Sub LoopDo()
Dim x as integer
For x =1 to 100
Dim i as integer
i = 2

Do while cells(i,5).value<>””
Cells(i,9).value=exp(-cells(i,5).value * x)

cells(2,13).formula=“=product(i2:i26)”

i=i+1

Loop

Next x
End sub
```

I want results in cells(2,13) will be extracted in column 13 (from row 2 to whatever needed) when one row will correspond one x value. 
How to do that?

Comment: Do you want to apply the formula '=product(i2:i26)' where cells value = x ?

Comment: Yes, because i need product of every range of cells(i,9) for each x

Comment: can you please Provide an example of the output excepted ? This is quite note Clear

Comment: Please add a screen shot of the output excepted

Comment: Sorry, I expect to get:
Cell(2,13) = product(i2:i26) for x =1
Cell(3,13) = product(i2:i26) for x =2

Cell(4,13) = product(i2:i26) for x =3

Etc

Comment: I do not quite understand, but maybe you need something like this: `Cells(1 + x, 13) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Product(Range("I2:I26"))`. If not try to better explain. There is an edit button below your post. When you click it you can edit your question.

Comment: That’s perfect!! Thank you very much!!!